# "cannot open shared object file: Input/output error" - for everything

Tags: linux, filesystems

`pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libarchive.so.13: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error`

Almost every command responds with something like this, each with a different shared object. At least the coreutils are functioning...

It just happened at a single moment, I suspect due to a bad package installation (I had an AUR update running in a separate SSH session that since disconnected).

I can't even access the pacman log, because... well...

When ls'ing /usr/share I get (trimmed response):

```
ls: cannot access libndr.so.0.0.3: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libsamdb.so: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libsamba-credentials.so.0: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libdcerpc.so: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libdcerpc-samr.so.0: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libSoundTouch.so.0: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libSoundTouch.so.0.0.0: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.1.11: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libclangLex.a: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libclangParse.a: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libclangAnalysis.a: Stale file handle
ls: cannot access libclangFrontendTool.a: Stale file handle
ls: cannot access libclangBasic.a: Input/output error
ls: cannot access libclangSema.a: Stale file handle
ls: cannot access libclangAST.a: Stale file handle
ls: cannot access libclangDriver.a: Stale file handle
```

Any idea how to start dealing with this? I should note that I don't have physical access to the machine (at probably won't have for a couple more days).

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell you?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `/usr/bin/dmesg: Input/output error`

Comment: Try `cat /proc/kmsg` in one session and accessing the filesystem in another session. This should show the kernel error messages if `dmesg` command fails like that.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Both sudo and su are inaccessible :'-( I'm going to get physical access to the computer today, hopefully `fsck` will get some results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something basic about SSDs that I don't understand, but I'll post this as hope to all future Googlers:

I backed-up everything I could (directory listings, mostly - and some files that were still accessible), then rebooted ('cause hunch). EVERYTHING CAME BACK TO NORMAL. I don't know how a reboot can resolve disk issues, but apparently - it can.

Cross your fingers and have hope, future readers!